# Change pandas plot background color

Tags: python, colors, background, matplotlib, pandas

Is it possible to change the background in a pandas chart?

I would like to change the background from white and the line to orange but I cannot find any documentation to do that.

I am using the pandas as follows:

```
import pandas.io.data as web
import numpy as np

gs = web.get_data_yahoo('gs')['Close']
gs = gs.pct_change()
gs.plot()
```

Is it possible to change the background to black or any other color?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`plot()` in `pandas` are build on `matplotlib`. The right way is just to access the plot axes object and change its bgcolor: change the lastlines to:

```
P=gs.plot()
P.set_axis_bgcolor('g') #or any HTML colorcode, (R,G,B) tuple, (R,G,B,A) tuple, etcetc.
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be deprecated. Use  `P.set_facecolor('g')` instead.